# Filter set of latlong locations based on users latlong location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have an array of latlong for events, and I am trying to determine, based on the user's latlong, if they're at one of the events. I am sure I can use Google Maps JavaScript API to accomplish this, but I simply need it to do the filtering for me, I don't need to render a map. What is the best method for this, or please point me to a jsfiddle or something.

Thanks in advance.
- Tom

Comment: Although the question is interesting it may be closed as [**not a real question**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) as it shown no effort in your part to find an answer & little information for us to help .What have you researched? What have you tried? What errors? Sample data ?? etc. If you **EDIT** your question to address these points It will help us help you

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed! You may only use Google Maps Data if you are displaying a map that is publicly accessible. See [**section 9.1 of the TOS**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1) and **10.1.1 (g) ["No Use of Content without a Google Map.](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1)**":

Comment: He did not say that any of the LatLng's come from Google-Maps.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, but he did say that he wants to use the Google Maps JavaScript API and not display a map. :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the question, my guess was that he want's to achieve this without the Maps-API, e.g. by using a custom calculation.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, No worries. :-) In fact, leaving the GM API alone would be even easier and all legal, as he could simply do it with a spatially enabled database, but he's not asking that.